# How generate java client with jaxws-maven-plugin from wsdl and extra xsd:s?

Tags: java, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am about to generate a java client side from a wsdl for a service that also might return subclasses defound in external xsd:s that is not referenced from the wsdl.

If I generate from the wsdl with jaxws-maven-plugin I get just the classes that is explicit referenced from the wsdl.

SO in some way I need to tell jaxws-maven-plugin to also generate from some extra xsd:s.

I manage to generate the classes from the external xsd:s into an other maven project but  during runtime it says some types is not found. So I guess they all need to exist in the same jar.

Best regards
Fredrik